# Intersection of open sets of infinite measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Does the intersection open sets of infinite measure converge to a given set? That is, does

$$\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \;\; (k,\infty)$$

converge to a set?

Edit: Not asking what the limit of the descending sets are, that is clearly $\infty$ since each set has infinite measure. I am asking whether or not the intersection of the descending sets has a value.

Comment: Intersections of arbitrary family of sets are well-defined in set-theoretic level, without references to the concept such as 'measure-theory' or 'notion of convergence of sets'. And in this case, the answer is simply $\varnothing$. You can check that $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}(k,\infty)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that misses every real number, owing to the Archimedean property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the measure of $(\infty,\infty)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091708/what-is-the-measure-of-infty-infty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to ask what is the measure of the intersection, then we can actually observe that the given intersection is empty, so the measure is zero. To see this, say there were an element in this intersection, call it $x$. There must exist $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $x<N$. Now, note that $x\notin (M,\infty)$ for all $M\geq N,$ a contradiction.